# lpr: How to specify the page range "3 to end"?

Tags: printing, cups

The [CUPS doc](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html) does not say how to specify a page range such as "3 to end". Can this be done without knowing the number of pages of the document? So something like `lpr -o page-ranges=3-end -P myprinter`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify a number that's more than the actual number of pages, Cups ignores the request for pages beyond the end.

```
lpr -o page-ranges=3-999999999 …
```

(Don't use more than nine `9`s as Cups will silently wrap numbers around beyond 2<sup>31</sup>.)

---

Back when this question was asked, Cups could do it on its own. If you left out one of the sides of the range, it meant the end. `page-ranges=-42` was a (rather useless) shortcut for `page-ranges=1-42`. To specify a range that goes till the end of the file, you could leave the end part blank: `page-ranges=3-`. Sadly this feature seems to have disappeared.

Comment: well done, Gilles. This is funny, in my "alias", I defined `-o page-ranges=-`, but this did *not* work, so at least one of the numbers has to be specified :-)

Comment: I thought I suggested this to @MariusHofert since I noticed you could do this with `psselect` but in looking through my answer I noticed I didn't. Good catch Gilles, and sorry MariusHofert that I neglected to mention trying this explicitly.

Comment: This solution does not work on my machine (Fedora 28). `lpr -o page-ranges=8- a.pdf` unexpectedly prints *all* pages. Strangely, `lpr -o page-ranges=-8` behaves as expected, and prints the first 8 pages.

Comment: @Chadversary Doesn't work for me either on Ubuntu 18.04. The feature seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score 6):

#### lpr ranges

I'm not sure about the "end" bit but you can try this method if you know the last page number in the series:

```
$ lpr -P myprinter -o page-ranges=3-10
```

#### lpoptions

You can try querying the printer to see what options it has to offer.

```
$ lpoptions -p <printer name> -l
```

#### Example

```
$ lpoptions -p mfc-8480dn -l
OptionTrays/Number of Input Trays: 1Trays *2Trays
PageSize/Media Size: *Letter Legal Executive A4 A5 A6 Env10 EnvMonarch EnvDL EnvC5 EnvISOB5 EnvISOB6
BrMediaType/BrMediaType: *PLAIN THIN THICK THICKERPAPER2 BOND TRANSPARENCIES ENV ENVTHICK ENVTHIN
InputSlot/InputSlot: MPTRAY TRAY1 TRAY2 *AUTO
Duplex/Duplex: DuplexTumble DuplexNoTumble *None
Resolution/Resolution: 300dpi *600dpi 2400x600dpi 1200dpi
TonerSaveMode/Toner Save: *Off On
Sleep/Sleep Time [Min.]: *PrinterDefault 2minutes 10minutes 30minutes
```

#### psselect

If you have a postscript (PS) stream that you're attempting to send to the `lpr` command you can use the command `psselect` to select ranges of pages from the postscript stream.

#### Sample data

- *PDF*: A Sample PDF file is available here, titled: [example.pdf](http://www.selab.isti.cnr.it/ws-mate/example.pdf)
- *text*: We can make a example .txt file like so:

  ```
  $ seq 1000 > example.txt
  ```

#### Examples

***text***

*using enscript*

```
$ enscript sample.txt -o - | psselect -p3- | ps2pdf - textfile.pdf
[ 16 pages * 1 copy ] left in -
[3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16] 
Wrote 14 pages, 30417 bytes

$ enscript sample.txt -o - | psselect -p3-5 | ps2pdf - textfile.pdf
[ 16 pages * 1 copy ] left in -
[3] [4] [5] Wrote 3 pages, 16329 bytes
```

*using paps*

```
$ paps sample.txt - | psselect -p3- | ps2pdf - textfile.pdf
[3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16] [17] [18] [19] 
Wrote 17 pages, 44159 bytes
[saml@grinchy bin]$ paps sample.txt - | psselect -p3-5 | ps2pdf - textfile.pdf
[3] [4] [5] Wrote 3 pages, 15851 bytes
```

***PDF***

```
$ pdftops example.pdf - | psselect -p3- | ps2pdf - pdffile.pdf
[3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] Wrote 8 pages, 687796 bytes

$ pdftops example.pdf - | psselect -p3-5 | ps2pdf - pdffile.pdf
[3] [4] [5] Wrote 3 pages, 372422 bytes
```

#### Sending to lpr

You can change the above commands so that instead of piping the output to `ps2pdf`, send it to `lpr`, like so:

```
$ pdftops example.pdf - | psselect -p3-5 | lpr -P myprinter
```

#### What else?

You can control the number of columns using either `lpr` or `enscript` or `paps`. You can also control the duplex (double sided style) using `lpr` too.

#### Examples

*2 columns*

```
$ paps --columns=2 sample.txt - | psselect -p3-5 | ps2pdf - textfile.pdf
[3] [4] [5] Wrote 3 pages, 22244 bytes

$ enscript -2 sample.txt -o - | psselect -p3-5 | ps2pdf - textfile.pdf
[ 8 pages * 1 copy ] left in -
[3] [4] [5] Wrote 3 pages, 19700 bytes

$ pdftops example.pdf - | psselect -p3-5 | lpr -o number-up=2
```

*duplex*

```
$ pdftops example.pdf - | psselect -p3-5 | lpr -o number-up=2 -o sides=two-sided-short-edge
```

#### References

- [Using the Printing System](http://www.ge.infn.it/calcolo/stampanti/lpr_guide.html)
- [Printing from DICE project](http://www.dice.inf.ed.ac.uk/units/user_support/docs/cups-printing.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. As I said in my post, I was hoping for an answer for the case where you do *not* know the number of pages in the document. Of course, you can use various tools to find this out, but the options are simply "alias-like" commands I define, so I was hoping for a very simple solution using `lpr`'s `-o page-ranges` directly (I tried `end` but this did not work).

Comment: @MariusHofert - looking through the docs I didn't see a way to give an open ended range like that to `lpr`. You can use the `psselect -p3-` though to get a postscript range of pages and then pipe it to `lpr`.

Comment: just figured out that one could always specify `1-99999`... probably the easiest solution