# Zathura: how to print specified pages

Tags: printing, zathura

I would like to print some pages from a large pdf file within [Zathura](http://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) (typically the current, or a range of pages).

What is the syntax to do that?

**Edit:** The solution was quite obvious... By the developer himself:

> Select the page range in the printing dialog?

So yes, there **is** a printing dialog, the classic Gtk+ printing dialog with the common options that allows me to do whatever I might want. I just need to type `:print`. I was actually expecting from Zathura to type arguments to select the printer and other stuffs.

At least, next time someone wonders how to print with Zathura, he might find this post.

Comment: Do you mean in batch mode (i.e. without using the "Print" dialog)? Also, do you mean print to file or print to a "real" printer?

Comment: Would you please consider removing your solution from the question and posting it as an answer? Then either mark it or the other answer that mentions this as "accepted" as there is a solution to this unlike the current accepted answer.

Comment: I wondered how to print in Zathura, and found this post. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw no way to do this using the `:print` command. Nothing was mentioned about this capability in the man pages or on the documentation on the project's website, so I'm inclined to think that it's not currently available.

I created an issue in their issue tracker to either:

1. explain how to do this
2. implement this feature down the road

This is the ticket: [Possible to print a range of pages from a PDF?](http://bugs.pwmt.org/issue357)

Comment: I feel bad, there is actually a print popup window... I I thought the exact same thing as you and I didn't wanted to type "print" without knowing if it will print the document without confirmation. And after some search on the internet I only found old messaging saying that it was not possible or that it was the same syntax than lpr, etc. I wanted a clear answer.

Comment: @Maxime - yeah a lot of times with these stripped down types of tools their nice initially but then start to feel too constrictive b/c they're missing some perceived basic feature. You could always print directly from the command line, I believe you can say you want to print a range of pages, there are Q&A's about that on this site.  Might be something to get you by in the short term.

Comment: See this Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89121/lpr-how-to-specify-the-page-range-3-to-end

Comment: Yes thank you. In fact my question my related to this one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99392/print-dialog-crashes-any-workaround so the `:print` command makes Zathura to crash so I might be interested by learning how to use `lpr` (and its options).

Answer (score 4):

When doing `:print` you'll have a printing dialog  as mentioned in [the slm' closed ticket](http://bugs.pwmt.org/issue357). You can then choose pages range.

Comment: This is no new information compared with the question.

Comment: This answer was written before question enhancement. it was just a simple solution to print pages range. We can see the author's (@maxime) comment : _ I feel bad, there is actually a print popup window... _. But now, it's completely deprecated.